# One sample test of uniformity in R

Tags: r, hypothesis-testing, distributions, variance, uniform-distribution

I have a dataset of two columns: one with IDs and one with a column of single digits (0-9) (see below). I would like a statistical significance test for whether the data is uniform. Ideally, I would actually like to test whether certain groups of the data are uniform (i.e. is ID=1 uniform or is ID=2 uniform).

There are a number of possible ways to do this, though given my actual data's structure, I think a test for the variance of uniform distribution would be best (the equation for uniform distribution variance is $\frac{(b-a)^2}{12}$.

Does anyone have any ideas of where I could start or whether there are any existing R packages for something like this?

```
ID     Digits
1         9            
1         4            
1         4            
2         6            
2         5            
2         3
2         3
```

Comment: I presume that's just an example of your data, not the full data set. Is it that you want (a) one overall test of deviation from uniformity, (b) a single statistic giving a combined measure of deviation from uniformity for each group or (c) individual tests of deviation from uniformity.

Comment: Yes, that is an example of what my data looks like. I would like something closer to C, individual tests of deviation from uniformity. My idea was a test of variance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's address the underlying statistical question, and then briefly mention doing that in R.

You want to do a test for a discrete uniform distribution applied to each subgroup. So let's think of a specific subgroup. You have a sequence of digits (which we can tabulate as a set of counts). For example:

```
  9 4 3 1 1 9 9 3 6 3 7 9 5 8 5 6 0 4 1 4 8 6 3 7 3 9 1 9 1 1 1 6 7 6 2 5 5 5
   8 8 1 4 2 5 7 8 6 0 2 6

> table(x)
x
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
2 8 3 5 4 6 7 4 5 6
```

i.e. '0' occurred twice, '1' occurred 8 times and so on.

How do we test for uniformity?

You suggested testing variance. I initially assumed you mean the variance of the distribution of digit-values (which would be viable as a test statistic for particular kinds of deviation), but I now wonder if maybe you mean *the variance of the observed counts*.

Let's discuss both, second first:

a) Variance of counts of digits. That is, if the observed count for digit $i$ is $O_i$, in this case I guess you mean to take a constant times $\sum_{i=0}^9(O_i-\bar{O})^2$ (a sample variance of the *counts* would make that constant $\frac{1}{(10-1)}$, but let's leave that to one side for a moment).

That's actually a pretty good idea, and I want to tweak it just the tiniest bit, for reasons that will become clearer in a moment.

Note that $\bar O = \frac{1}{10}\sum O_i=\frac{n}{10}$, which is just the expected count for each digit -- let's call that $E_i$ (that may seem unnecessary, but you'll have to indulge me a moment).

Then the sum of squared deviations from expected is now $\sum_{i=0}^9(O_i-E_i)^2$, which is proportional to $\frac{1}{E_i}\sum_{i=0}^9(O_i-E_i)^2=\sum_{i=0}^9\frac{(O_i-E_i)^2}{E_i}$ ... which is just the usual *chi-square* goodness of fit statistic. So the variance of the counts of digits is (apart from a scaling constant) a well-known test for goodness of fit to the hypothesized uniform distribution of counts.

[This could be done in R by calling `tapply` on your second column of data with a function `f`, where `f=function(x) chisq.test(table(x))$p.value` and the index being the ID]

b) Now if you mean the variance of the distribution of *digit-values*, that will have very good power against *particular kinds* of non-uniformity, such as:

[image]

... specifically, nonuniform distributions with larger or smaller variance than the discrete uniform. But it will have very poor power against non-uniform distributions with very similar variance to the discrete uniform, such as either of these:

[image] 
[image]

If you're only interested in non-uniforms with larger or smaller variance than the discrete uniform and don't care about the later possible alternatives, this is fine. There are a couple of ways to go about testing this, which I'll go into if you definitely want this option.

But note carefully: the variance of the discrete uniform on 0,1,...,9 is not $\frac{(9-0)^2}{12}$. That's the continuous uniform. The [discrete uniform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28discrete%29) on 0,1,...,9 has variance $\frac{(10^2-1)}{12}=\frac{(9\times 11)}{12}=8.25$

---

As requested, here's one test of variance. This one is easy to do.

Consider the variance statistic about the expected value for the 
uniform rather than the sample mean:

$T = \frac{1}{n}\sum_i (X_i-\frac{9}{2})^2$

This should have better power than a test using the ordinary sample variance would have against mean shifts. This is also quite easy to work out the asymptotic 
distribution of:

$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sqrt{n}(T_n-8.25) \sim N(0,52.8)\,,$

and convergence is so rapid that it's reasonable to use this at fairly small sample sizes.

In the right tail it looks to be quite 
good above about n=50 (personally, I'd happily use it down to about 
n=10, but I'm not fussy about exactness of type I error rates). In the 
right tail it looks fine down below n=10.

[Even at n=5, it's not so bad -- the left hand tail was giving a true 
significance level of about 2% for a nominal 2.5% left hand tail normal 
critical value.]

One can make a test with the ordinary sample variance, but it approaches its 
asymptotic distribution considerably more slowly.

To do that, we can actually compute the variance of the sample variance (it
involves fourth moments), and we could then use an asymptotic approximation to the
distribution of the variance (but as I mentioned it comes in relatively more slowly
than the variance about 4.5). Or we could simulate from the null distribution at any given sample size to get an approximate p-value (if I was going to use the variance, this is what I'd do).

Comment: Hi, your comments were incredibly helpful. I'm not sure your suggestion in (a) is quite what I am looking for, though please let me know if I have misunderstood. Your plots in (b) are essentially the visualization of the data I have for some of the IDs. I am not particularly interested in their shape but rather whether each ID's density distribution resembles a uniform distribution. Variance is one logical possibility I had thought of, though you raise some reasonable concerns. I would certainly be open to the suggestions you say you have of alternatives. Thank you so much thus far!

Comment: I'm afraid I don't quite understand your comment. How can you not be interested in shape, yet be interested in whether it resembles a uniform. "Uniform" *is* a description of the shape!

Comment: I apologize for the confusing comment. You are correct in that I am interested in whether a particular density distribution statistically resembles or does not resemble a uniform distribution for digit values. After re-reading, I believe I had simply misunderstood you. I would be interested in your comments on a test of whether digit density distributions have larger or smaller variance than the discrete uniform.

Comment: Okay, I'll write a little more about that case ... as long as it's clear (as illustrated by my two examples) that you can have clear nonuniformity yet have the same sample variance of the digits values as for uniformity.

Comment: I've added a bit where I describe one test based on the variance about the (known\*) mean. ... \* (under the null hypothesis)